# How to run I2C communication between ESP8266 and SN532?

Tags: arduino, esp8266

I have a question "How to run I2C communication between ESP8266 Lolin and SN532 by elechouse?". I tried to use a lot of ways, but using elechouse library[library](https://github.com/elechouse/PN532/tree/master) I always get in serial this "Didn't find PN53X board". I And I'm trying to start an example: ReadTag of basic elechouse lib. IDE is PlatformIO.

Code of ReadTag:

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <PN532_I2C.h>
#include <PN532.h>
#include <NfcAdapter.h>

PN532_I2C pn532_i2c(Wire);
NfcAdapter nfc = NfcAdapter(pn532_i2c);


void setup(void) {
    //Wire.begin(4, 3);
    Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial.println("NDEF Reader");
    nfc.begin();
}

void loop(void) {
    Serial.println("\nScan a NFC tag\n");
    if (nfc.tagPresent())
    {
        NfcTag tag = nfc.read();
        tag.print();
    }
    delay(5000);
}
```

I tried to declare SDA and SCL with `Wire.begin(4, 3);`, but it still doesn't work! Maybe someone knows solution?

Comment: I2C is an electrical standard, so there may be something wrong with your circuit. This may be more appropriate for the EE group. Have you sized the pullup resistors properly, if they are not already included? Are you using relatively short wires? Are you using the correct pins for I2C functionality on your micro? Let's start there first.

Comment: Which are correct pins for it? Is there something defined on ESP8266 Lolin?

Comment: You'll need to check the docs for SCL/SDA to find the location of the hardware module. Unless you've got good reason not to, use those. If your MCU supports software I2C on any pin, you can use a software i2c library. I'm not sure off the top of my head if Wire supports this. You'll need to check the other items, like pulllup resistors and sizing. I2c only works with correctly sized pullup resistors.

Comment: Default SDA and SCL don't help!

Comment: And what about your resistor sizing

Comment: Which ones? I have connected PN532 directly to ESP8266 Lolin. Or I need to have some resistors between them?

Comment: Ok, sounds like this may be the issue. I2C devices communicate by pulling down voltages rather than pulsing voltages. To do this, SCL and SDA need to be at logic level voltage. To limit current sinking through the devices, resistors are used. I think their typically between 50-500 ohms. See this diagram https://cdn.sparkfun.com/assets/5/f/5/a/1/51adff65ce395ff71a000000.png. The rest of that article should give some more background if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

The module has an onboard voltage regulator, that uses 5V logical level in I2C mode according to the [documentation](https://dangerousthings.com/wp-content/uploads/PN532_Manual_V3-1.pdf).
The SPI and HSA (high speed UART) modes use 3.3V for logical level.